# Looping a function and tracking if there are 4+ identical values in a row

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to track if there are 4+ identical values in a row, and if so return 'red' for each of the values.

My problem is I can only figure out how to do this after the first three identical values have been identified. This is because I'm comparing the previous value with the current, rather than looking ahead. I'm not sure how to look ahead.

```
function(d, i) {

      if(i !== 0 && previous_d === d)
        tally++;
      else
        tally = 0;

      previous_d = d;

      return (tally >= 4) ? 'red' : '#363636';
 })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/everina/f2L2t9tw/2/ - this is a discrete bar, you will notice the first 3 lines of a 4+ chain are black but should be red.

How may I have it so it looks head and sees if it's part of a 4+ chain of identical values, and return red if it is.

Comment: It looks like you need a bit of look-behind. Something along the lines of storing the index at which you first picked up the value `d` and then coloring from there to the index at which you last found it.

Comment: can't you just keep track of the maximum value of the tally and if that is > 4 then return red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible solution. During the initial pass, take note of when the tally becomes four. This tells you where your starting index is for that set of four items. Then do a second pass to assign the earlier items the correct values.

Below is an example. `indices` is an array declared at the top of the `discreteChart` function.

```
.attr('stroke', function(d, i) {

  if(i !== 0 && previous_d === d) {
    tally++;
  } else {
    tally = 1;
  }
  if (tally === 4) {
    indices.push(i - tally);
  }

  previous_d = d;

  return (tally >= 4) ? 'red' : '#363636';
})
.attr('stroke', function (d, i) {
  var n;
  for (n = 0; n < indices.length; n++) {
    if (i > indices[n] && i < indices[n] + 4) {
      return 'red';
    }
  }
  return this.attributes.getNamedItem('stroke').value;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

We should prepare some array based on `dataset` with a tally length on corresponding index. To achieve this we prepare some array of objects with an item value and tally length...

```
var data = [];
dataset.forEach(function(item, index) {
  if (0 === data.length || data[data.length - 1].item !== item) {
    data.push({'item': item, 'length': 1});
  } else {
    data[data.length - 1].length++;
  }
});
```

...and then expand it into flat form:

```
var tallyLength = [];
data.forEach(function(item) {
  for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    tallyLength.push(item.length);
  }
});
```

So we can set any attributes according `tallyLength` array items:

```
.attr('stroke', function(d, i) {
  return (tallyLength[i] >= 4) ? 'red' : '#363636';
})
```